# Git-svn: managing multiple remote tracking branchs

Tags: svn, git, git-svn, branch

Currently I'm trying out exporting Git repository history into svn via git-svn and using grafts method. As of now, I have successfully exported the git history into svn. But because of the grafting method and that my git repository is cloned from the actual repository, I ended up having TWO remote branches like that of below.

```
o-----o-----o-----o-----o remotes/trunk, next
 \    A'    B'    C'    D'
  \
   \o----o-----o-----o remotes/origin/master, origin/master, master
    A    B     C     D
```

Both branches reflects the same commits as A' is that of git history imported into svn.What I'm trying to do is the svn will act as a one way repository where only when a release is ready go into production, then I will commit changes into SVN.

**Would like to know if there is anyway to streamline the two branches into a single trunk/branch.**

I've tried using ***git update-ref refs/remotes/trunk origin/master*** but this result in failure when trying to commit changes into svn due to duplcated transaction.

Hope someone can advise me on this. I hope I'm clear with my issue.